# Kafka Connect JDBC Sink Connector giving Invalid Object Name Error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Jdbc Sink Connector with following configs:

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "connection.password": "**",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "topic1, topic2, topic3",
    "batch.size": "1000",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "batch.max.rows": "1000",
    "table.whitelist": "topic1, topic2, topic3",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "delete.enabled": "true",
    "connection.user": "username",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "name": "sink",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:port;database=dbname;trustServerCertificate=true",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "pk.fields": "id"
}
```

Although I do not include table4 on the consumer side, I get the error Invalid object name 'table4' on the  producer side. Can anyone please help me?

Also on the consumer side, when sending image type data, I get the error nvarchar is incompatible with image.